# facing issue with connecting to SharePoint Online from Python due to cert issue

Tags: python, sharepoint, ssl-certificate

I am trying a get a list items from SharePoint to Python, here is the code I am using for the poc

```
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url='https://SharePointSiteURL')
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username='MyUser@Company.onmicrosoft.com',password='MyPassword'):
ctx = ClientContext('https://SharePointSiteURL', ctx_auth)
lists = ctx.web.lists
ctx.load(lists)
```

The issue I am getting following error
"Error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /GetUserRealm.srf (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)')))"

I am trying to set the ssl-verify=none to get the poc moving, Any ideas on how I can do that with AuthenticationContext

Thank you
Nate

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version `RequestOptions.verify` property is exposed which allows:

> to control whether to verify the server's TLS certificate which accepts:
>
> - boolean value (defaults to `True`)
> - string value, which represents path to a CA bundle to use

**Example**

Certificate verification could be disabled via underlying HTTP request object as demonstrated below:

```
def disable_ssl(request):
    request.verify = False  # Disable certification verification


ctx = ClientContext.connect_with_credentials("https://contoso.sharepoint.com",
                                             UserCredential(username,
                                                            password)

ctx.get_pending_request().beforeExecute += disable_ssl
web = ctx.web
ctx.load(web)
ctx.execute_query()
print(web.properties["Url"])
```

**Note**

Once disabled, `urllib3` might complain with [`InsecureRequestWarning` warning](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning) which is expected given unverified HTTPS request is being made to host
`{tenant}.sharepoint.com`. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised.

**Installation**

Since it requires the latest version, it could be installed from GitHub (until it gets published in PyPI):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client.git
```

Comment: Thank you Vadim for writing the code and helping out with the issue. Here is the error I am getting. site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1004: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LocalUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py", line 36, in execute_query
    response.raise_for_status()

Comment: File "C:\LocalUser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://MySharePointSiteURL/_api/Web

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: import urllib3 urllib3.disable_warnings()

Comment: After urllib3.disable_warnings() , I am getting similar error                           
 File "C:\,,,,Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://mysharepointsiteurl/_api/Web

Comment: Hey Nate, what kind of site are you trying to connect to, is it SharePoint Online?  p.s.And i think it is discouraged to have a discussion here, maybe you could raise an issue in GitHub instead?

Comment: Thanks Vadim, Yes, it is SharePointOnline site. I agree, will raise the request in github

Comment: Could it be that this feature is removed again? I am getting the error: `'ClientContext' object has no attribute 'get_pending_request'`

Comment: @Siete, it is, get_pending_request has been renamed into pending_request